# Google API get status of purchase inap is returning "Not found"

Tags: php, android, in-app-billing

I refered google play android api to check the purchase and consumption status of an in-app item. but return the error as below:

`C:\Program Files\VertrigoServ\www\inapp\index.php:74:null
Not Found`

I can not understand why he does not return me not a valid json, it just returns me a text saying "Not Found"

I use the function to `getToken()`, she works perfect... but the function
`getStatusInapp($pProductIdStr, $lAccessToken)` doesn't work

What I doing wrong?

```
function getToken(){

GLOBAL $lPackageNameStr; // Name of package Name (com.example.app)
GLOBAL $client_id; // my client id from google
GLOBAL $client_secret; // my client secret from google
GLOBAL $refresh_token; // the refresh token
GLOBAL $pReceiptStr; // token of inap purchase

$url ="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token";
$fields = array(
   "client_id"=>$client_id,
   "client_secret"=>$client_secret,
   "refresh_token"=>$refresh_token,
   "grant_type"=>"refresh_token");

$ch = curl_init($url);
//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
//execute post
$lResponse_json = (curl_exec($ch));
$lAccessToken = json_decode($lResponse_json)->{'access_token'};
//close connection
curl_close($ch);
return $lAccessToken;
}

function getStatusInapp($pProductIdStr, $lAccessToken){

GLOBAL $lPackageNameStr; // Name of package Name (com.example.app)
GLOBAL $client_id; // my client id from google
GLOBAL $client_secret; // my client secret from google
GLOBAL $refresh_token; // the refresh token
GLOBAL $pReceiptStr; // token of inaap purchase

/*
# What is the correct way to sku?

$pProductIdStr = "teste_01";
------------ or --------------
$pProductIdStr = "com.example.app.teste_01";
------------ or --------------
$pProductIdStr = "inap:com.example.app:teste_01";

# On Google Play Developer Console the sku is:> teste_01


*/

$lURLStr =  ("https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v2/applications/$lPackageNameStr/purchases/$pProductIdStr/purchases/$pReceiptStr");

$curl = curl_init($lURLStr);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$curlheader[0] = "Authorization: Bearer " . $lAccessToken;
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $curlheader);

$json_response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

//echo $json_response;
$responseObj = json_decode($json_response,true);
var_dump($responseObj);
echo $json_response;
}

/*
| Execute...
*/

getStatusInapp($pProductIdStr, getToken());
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have the API endpoint path wrong. The [Purchases.products: get](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/products/get) documentation describes the url as:

> https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v2/applications/**packageName**/purchases/products/**productId**/tokens/**token**

Change your `$lURLStr` to:

```
"https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v2/applications/$lPackageNameStr/purchases/products/$pProductIdStr/tokens/$pReceiptStr"
```

Comment: Really thanks!! and productId be is 

`$pProductIdStr = "teste_01";
------------ or --------------
$pProductIdStr = "com.example.app.teste_01";
------------ or --------------
$pProductIdStr = "inap:com.example.app:teste_01";`

Comment: the productId should be exactly the same as what is shown in the Google Play Developer Console. What ever is shown in the list of in-app products in the parenthesise of the Name/ID column is what you need to set as your $pProductIdStr.